# Can I say "Bran's bachelor's"?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

My friend is Bran.

He had a bachelor party.

Can I title a photo album *Bran’s bachelor’s*?

Comment: No, no you can't. *Bachelors* for a 'bachelors party' may be okay, but *'Bran's bachelor's'* as a noun would be ungrammatical I suppose.

Comment: It's fine. You could call it Cheez Whiz if you wanted to too.

Comment: This is the kind of question that generates a lot of disagreement. It's your photo album, so you can call it whatever you want, as a couple of folks here have said. I agree with them. If you're going to publish and sell it, then you might want to consider a title that everyone will understand, like "Bran's Bachelor Party". On the other hand, you might want to give it a mysterious title so that people will pick it up and look at it to figure out what the mysterious title means. That's just a marketing decision.

Comment: Using "bachelor's" as a noun is fine in informal speech. (Before I earned my Master's, I earned my Bachelor's. Here is a picture of the diploma, which I have titled "MetaEd's Bachelor's".) If you are aiming for a formal tone, "Bran's Bachelor Party" would be a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

If it’s for you and your friends, you can call it what you like. If Bran’s bachelor party is what *Bran's bachelor's* means to you, then go ahead and use it.

Comment: OP means to say he wants to drop *party* altogether.

Comment: Then he can, as I have said.

Answer (score 2):

*Bran's bachelor party* is correct ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_party) also thinks so), and just using "Bran's bachelor" would be confusing. *Bran's bachelor's* is also unclear as to what it is referring.

If you're looking for a shorter name, the Wikipedia article lists some other ways to call a *bachelor party* that are common in other countries, like *stag night* or *buck's party*.